# How to implement lead in Spark dataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to add column for next timestamp. I referred to various websites and created code similar to them.  However, an error has occurred.
How to fix it? and why I got error?

```
+--------------------+
|           Timestamp|
+--------------------+
|2014-04-01 12:00:...|
|2014-04-01 12:00:...|
|2014-04-01 12:00:...|
|2014-04-01 12:00:...|
|2014-04-01 12:00:...|
+--------------------+


w = Window.partitionBy(("Timestamp")).orderBy(("Timestamp"))
df_FD.withColumn("end_date", lead("Timestamp", 1).over(w)).show(3)
```

error message

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/3f/cj3qrr9x2dlgwkp147wyd6280000gn/T/ipykernel_20362/1581562162.py in <module>
      5 from pyspark.sql.functions import *
      6 w = Window.partitionBy(("Timestamp")).orderBy(("Timestamp"))
----> 7 df_FD.withColumn("end_date", lead("Timestamp", 1).over(w)).show(3)
      8 
.
.
.

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1334.showString.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
Exchange rangepartitioning(Timestamp#541 ASC NULLS FIRST, 200)
+- *(1) FileScan csv [Session_ID#540,Timestamp#541,Item_ID#542,Category#543] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/Users/iwayamayuto/Desktop/yoochoose-clicks.dat], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<Session_ID:string,Timestamp:timestamp,Item_ID:string,Category:string>
```

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because `Window.partitionBy(("Timestamp")).orderBy(("Timestamp"))` does not really make sense. Indeed, you are partitionning by `Timestamp` and then, within each partition order the records by `Timestamp`. In each partition all the `Timestamp` are equal so sorting by their value does not make sense and Spark does not allow it.

Computing the `lead` (or `lag` for that matter) of a value over the entire dataframe is tricky in spark. Spark is a distributed computing engine that makes partition wise computations. A solution would be not to partition the window:

```py
w = Window.orderBy(("Timestamp"))
df_FD.withColumn("end_date", lead("Timestamp", 1).over(w)).show()
```

Yet, that's not a good idea. Spark will throw a warning because that implies to put all the data inside the same partition. If that's possible, then you probably don't need spark in the first place. In general, this throw an OOM error.

There is a more complex solution though (explanations are in comments).

```py
# let's sort the dataframe by timestamp and add a column containing
# the partition index
sorted_df = df.orderBy("Timestamp")\
    .select("Timestamp", F.spark_partition_id().alias("partition_index"))\
    .cache()

# let's collect the minimal timestamp of each partition.
# That timestamp is the lead of the last timestamp of the previous partition
last_lead = sorted_df.groupBy("partition_index")\
    .agg(F.min(F.col("Timestamp")).alias("first_ts"))\
    .withColumn("partition_index", F.col("partition_index") - 1)

# Let's now create a window partitioned by partition index and ordered
# by Timestamp
w = Window.partitionBy("partition_index").orderBy("Timestamp")

# We compute the lead within each partition of w, and join with last_lead
# to compute the lead of the last item of each partition
sorted_df.withColumn("lead", F.lead("Timestamp", 1).over(w))\
    .join(last_lead, "partition_index", "left")\
    .withColumn("lead", F.coalesce("lead", "first_ts"))\
    .drop("first_ts").show()
```